# How do I deserialize a generic complex object from json?

Tags: c#, .net, json, reflection

I'm writing a generic method that takes a `Dictionary<string, object>` and uses reflection to hydrate an object of type `T`:

```
private T HydrateRequestObject<T>(Dictionary<string, object> requestParameters)
{
    dynamic requestObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    PropertyInfo[] requestProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in requestProperties)
    {
        //Fails with complex json
        prop.SetValue(requestObject, requestParameters[prop.Name]); 
    }

    return requestObject;
}
```

Currently, this handles simple parameters and properties such as:

```
"params" : {
    "CompanyID" : 50
}
```

But I also need to support complex parameters such as:

```
"params": {
    "Resource": {
      "FirstName": "test",
      "LastName": "test",
      "MiddleInitial": null,
      "Suffix": null,
      "Phone1": "test",
      "Phone2": null,
      "Phone3": null,
      "Email": "test",
      "AddressID": 47
    },
    "ResourceSaveType": 0
}
```

Currently I get an ArgumentException: "Object of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` cannot be converted to type `Resource`."  Is there a way to traverse the json to set all the properties in the object?  Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: Why are you re-inventing JSON.Net's serialization?

Comment: Try using `JObject.ToObject<T>()`.

Comment: @SLaks - I tried that but the Resource object is null.

Comment: The common term for this operation is 'deserialize' (not 'hydrate').  You might have better luck finding an answer with that term.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is no-one can know for sure what type should object resolve to - you have to specify it explicitly. Imagine for example you have also object of type Person in Dictionary (with properties FirstName, LastName) - how can json library know that Resource should be of Resource class ?

Explicitly specified type example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  public class Resource {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var foo = @"{
          ""$type"":""System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib"",
          ""Resource"":{""$type"":""ConsoleApplication1.Resource, ConsoleApplication1"",
             ""FirstName"":""rrr"",
             ""LastName"":null}}";

      var bar = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        foo, 
        new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings {
          TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects,
      });

    }
  }
}
```